# New Elasticsearch results don't show angle brackets

Tags: bug, status-completed, elasticsearch

Under the new elasticsearch, if you run a search where there will be html code listings included with the result snippets, instead of HTMLEncode()ing the angle brackets (<, >) that should be included, these characters are simply not shown at all.

Here's an example result:

[image: Missing Angle Brackets example]

Note the `% %` in the requisite free-hand circle. That should look like this: `<% %>`.

Comment: I could swear there was a frowny face icon on that bug tag a few minutes ago.

Comment: [Frowny face bug tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161600/169404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed the day after posting but I forgot to update this question, enjoy the long-ago bugfix!

Answer (score 2):

It works correctly in the title. The issue is occurring only in the answer excerpt:

[image]

[The same thing occurs with question excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=a+href+is%3Aquestion), unsurprisingly.

## Another, probably related bug

[That second query](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=a+href+is%3Aquestion) exposes a second bug: the hyperlinked title of the first result is broken and unclickable:

[image: Broken hyperlink]

Looks like improper escaping.

Comment: The escaping bug was a different thing, but fixed in the last deploy...thanks for the report.  I'll be looking into the angle brackets later today, I suspect we may be indexing without them...will update when I find the cause and see what we can fix.